What's the best possible way to run Linux on windows 10 if you have very limited free disk space? (Like only 5 GB)
I have found that there are a few very lightweight Linux distro to run in VM. Additionally, I learned that we can use WSL to run Ubuntu which only takes 1-2 GB. What option should I go with? I am a beginner in Linux. Just trying to learn developing software in Linux . It's okay if no GUI.

I do not know WSL. There are lightweight flavors of Ubuntu and then many other lightweight distributions. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
I use Kubuntu, a more middle weight flavor, but has worked on my old BIOS only system with limited RAM and new UEFI only system. I suggest an external SSD. I converted my smaller M.2 drive to USB when upgranding and find it almost as fast as internal SSD.

WSL is a good entry point. It's a virtual machine that integrates nicely with your windows, and which runs a real Linux system for you.
The default system is a Ubuntu which might grow bigger bigger quickly.
However, development libraries and compilers and other tools take space quickly. If you need to learn how to develop, it might not be optimal to constrain yourself to 5 GB, though certainly feasible, if you're used to remote development on Linux – which you're not, so do take some time to first learn how to use a Linux system before trying to develop on one, or you will lose a lot of time trying to understand how to understand errors etc.
Note that you can run other Linux distros in WSL, too, but honestly, you're a beginner. Start with the well-supported Ubuntu.

Thanks Marcus. So I cleaned up and now 14 gb free space. This is a 120 gb SSD.
So should I go with WSL-Ubunto route since I am a beginner? Or I have downloaded Oracle Virutal box, and run Ubuntu there?
In the official ubuntu download page it says to have "25 GB of free hard drive space"

WSL will work fine for you.
